# how to play a video on C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two computers.
When i run my code in first one everything is fine, video was playing.
When i run my code at the second computer, it throws me DirectXException was unhalndled.

My part of code for play a video is:

```
string path= Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"Photos\test.mp4");

var ofd = path;
label3.Text = ofd;
video.Owner = panel2;
panel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(634, 507);
video.Ending += new EventHandler(videocountdown_Ending);
video.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(634, 507);
```

And the details of the Exception is:

```
Error Code : -2147220891
Error String : VFW_E_UNSUPPORTED_STREAM
StackTrace :    in Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Video.Open(String fileName, Boolean autoRun)
   in Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Video..ctor(String fileName, Boolean autoRun)
   in WinFormCharpWebCam.mainWinForm.pictureBox1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) στο c:\ArtWedding\Form1.cs:γραμμή 133
   in System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   in System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   in System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   in System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   in System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   in System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   in System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   in System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   in System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   in System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   in System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   in WinFormCharpWebCam.Program.Main() στο c:\ArtWedding\Program.cs:γραμμή 18
   in System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
   in System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   in Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   in System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   in System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your code for video playback is not full. How do you launch it?
Looks like a codec problem at the second computer.

Comment: You're [missing a codec](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3260180/1193596).

Comment: i put the images with the exception details. Because i can't understand which codec missing and how to fix it.

Comment: Please read  [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post some code after that.

Comment: @NickName did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

From [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dd375623%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) site:

VFW_E_UNSUPPORTED_STREAM 0x80040265

Cannot play back the file: the format is not supported.

What format is the video you are trying to reproduce?

Comment: It is .mp4 but at first pc it's playing fine. at the second it throws me the error.

Comment: Seems like the second PC is missing a codec to reproduce the file then. Does the file work if you open it without your program? For example, using WMP or a similar program?

Answer (score 0):

You can window media player control

**To Add the Windows Media Player Control to the Toolbox**

On the File menu, click New Project.

In the New Project dialog box, click Windows Forms Application, and then click OK.

A new Windows Forms project opens.

Right-click the Toolbox, and click Choose Items.

The Customize Toolbox Items dialog box opens.

On the COM Components tab, select the Windows Media Player check box, and then click OK.

The Windows Media Player control appears on the current Toolbox tab.

When you add the Windows Media Player control to the Toolbox, Visual Studio automatically adds references to two libraries: AxWMPLib and WMPLib. The next step is to add the control to the Windows Form.

**To add the Windows Media Player control to a Windows Form**

Drag the Windows Media Player control from the Toolbox to the Windows Form.

In the Properties window, set the Dock property to Fill. 
You can do this by clicking the center square.

Double-click the title bar of the form to add the default Load event in the Code Editor.
Add the following code to the Form_Load event handler to load a video when the application opens.

This code sets the URL of the Windows Media Player to the media file that you have specified. Windows Media Player will automatically start to play when you set the URL property because the autoStart property is true by default.

Press F5 to run the code.

When the application opens, change the size of the form to full-screen by double-clicking the title bar of the form.

**You can also add WebBrowser to your form and then use  tag of HTML5**

Comment: i don't want to use windows media player. I want to put it at my panel. Because my panel capture for my camera too so i want to be in the same panel.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260120/programmatically-get-video-duration)